# Fragment shows only in top right

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout

Container for the fragment don't fill parent (on screenshot).
I have XML for main activity, constraint layout is the container for the fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/main_bottom_nav"/>
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And for the Fragment, data loads in recycler view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/users_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
    tools:context=".fragments.UsersFragment">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/users_recycler_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </ScrollView>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/users_progress_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

All layout width and height fields have "match_parent", but Fragment takes only 1/4 of screen
[image: emulator screenshot]

**UPDATE**
This is XML of recyclerview item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/user_card_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/user_card_constraint_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_name_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/last_name_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/last_name_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/first_name_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But actualy i have same problem in fragment without recyclerview

Comment: Can you post the item layout of the RecyclerView?

Comment: @Zain updated the question, added xml of recyclerview item

Answer (score 0):

I use ViewBinding feature and that is the problem.
Fragments metgod onCreateView was:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mBinding = FragmentUsersBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        return mBinding.getRoot();
    }
```

To solve the problem a have to attachToParent = false

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mBinding = FragmentUsersBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater(),container,false);
        return mBinding.getRoot();
    }
```